# keep input name in ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

can someone help me to keep original name in input as output

For example, i have a "Video.mp4" i need to convert it in mp3 as "Video.mp3"

***but i cant find it how to do it!***

i try
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn music.mp3`

but the output file is "music.mp3" and i dont want it

soo i try `ffmpeg -i A.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn *.mp3`

and it gives error like :

```
*.mp3: Invalid argument
```

pls help me :(

Answer (score 0):

[untried]

```
@echo off
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -b:a 192K -vn "%~n1.mp3"
```

As a batch file named `tomp3.bat`, use as `tomp3 "video.mp4"`

The quotes are not required unless the filename contains spaces (or some other symbols)

Comment: Doesn work,

%~1: No such file or directory

Comment: **use as tomp3 "video.mp4"**